# Converting a shell file to a windows batch file

Tags: shell, batch-file

I am told that I need to convert the following .sh file to a .bat file. I have absolutely no idea how to do that, can anyone give me some hints? It is a short code. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#enables execution from another directory
#p=/path/to/PDFAnalyser
p=.

java -cp $p/bin ;$p/../pdfXtk-Extras/jar/pdfxtk-extras.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk-GUI/jar/pdfxtk-gui.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/jar/pdfxtk-backend.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/lib/commons-logging.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/lib/fontbox-1.1.0.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/lib/jai_codec.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/lib/jai_core.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/lib/jai_imageio.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/lib/pdfbox-1.1.0.jar ;$p/../TouchGraph-Modified/jar/touchgraph-modified.jar ;$p/../TouchGraph-Modified/lib/TGWikiBrowser.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk/lib/xercesImpl.jar ;$p/../pdfXtk-Extras/lib/JavaOCR.jar at.ac.tuwien.dbai.pdfwrap.ProcessFile "$@"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean a Windows batch file, right?  If so, you should specify that in your question.

I don't have a complete answer, but I can give a few syntax tips.

`p=.` should be changed to `set p=.`.

`$p` should be changed to `%p%`.

To execute multiple commands on a line, separate them with `&` rather than `;` (or, better yet, just write one command per line).

Windows uses `\` rather than `/` as a directory separator.

The files are probably going to be in different locations, if they exist at all.  This assumes you're taking a `.sh` file from a Unix-like system and creating a `.bat` file for a Windows system.  If they're both the same system (probably because you're using Cygwin), you should mention that as well.

There is no straightforward way to translate a shell script to a batch file.  They're going to be running on different systems.  If you have no idea how to do it, your best bet is to find someone who does.

Answer (score 1):

Some more tips:

Lines starting with `#` are comments. Use `rem` in the batch file.

The token for all command line arguments `%@` must be replaced with `%*` for the batch file.